# Automatic adding optional fileds in request body

Tags: python, post, python-requests

The essence of the problem: there is one endpoint, for example https://api.ventrata.com/octo/availability. And there is a header `Octo-Capbilities: octo/content, octo/pricing, octo/pickups ....` The values are optional. Certain values can add fields to the query body. For example `octo-pricing` adds the `currency` field to the query.

Bottom line: how do I implement this optionality through python? I have a function:

```
def availability_post(headers, product_id: str, option_id: str, date_start: datetime.date,
              date_end: datetime.date, units: list[dict[str, Union[str, int]]],
              capabilities: Optional[list[str]] = None):
    body = {
        "productId": product_id,
        "optionId": option_id,
        "localDateStart": date_start.isoformat(), 
        "localDateEnd": date_end.isoformat(),
        "units": units
    }

    if capabilities is not None:
        if "pricing" in capabilities:
            body["currency"] = ???

        if "pickups" in capabilities:
            body["pickupRequested"] = ???
            body["pickupPointId"] = ???

        if "offers" in capabilities:
            body["offerCode"] = ???

     response = r.post(ROOT_URL, json=body, headers=headers)

     return response.json()
```

How can I get the values of optional fields **nicely**? There can be many such fields and I don't want to list them as optional function parameters

Comment: [dict.update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)?

Comment: @HTF. In principle this will work, but it is assumed that the end user does not need to know the names of the fields in the query that are added at certain capabilites